# haproxy: get the host name

Tags: http, https, haproxy

I am trying to get the requester host/ip as it comes to haproxy node.
My haproxy config is as below:

```
frontend www-http
    bind *:9000
    http-request redirect location https://%fi:9143

frontend www-https
    bind *:9143 ssl crt /root/keys.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server server1 1.1.1.1:9080 cookie server1 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

So here, if any http request comes, then I need to forward to https.
Now request may come either with ip address or hostname in fully qualified form, like

```
http://10.10.10.10:9000
```

this needs to be forwarded to https://10.10.10.10:9143

Again, the request may come hostname in fully qualified form, like

```
http://myhost.domain.com:9000
```

this needs to be forwarded to https://myhost.domain.com:9143

basically 10.10.10.10 and myhost.domain.com is same system.

Now with the above haproxy configuration, I am not able to get the below, as it is %fi (frontend_ip), so it is redirecting to https://10.10.10.10:9143

So my question is how I can get the haproxy node's ip/host as it comes to haproxy.

I tried below options, which did not work:

```
http-request redirect location https://%f:9143
http-request redirect location https://%[req.hdr(Host)]:9143
```

from https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/log_format_rules.html

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I set a dynamic variable in HAProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333496/how-do-i-set-a-dynamic-variable-in-haproxy) for additional details, but using that as a base, here is what should work for you:

```
frontend www-http
    bind *:9000

    # Redirect user from http port to https port
    http-request set-var(req.hostname) req.hdr(Host),field(1,:),lower
    http-request redirect code 301 location https://%[var(req.hostname)]:9143 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend www-https
    bind *:9143 ssl crt /root/keys.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server server1 1.1.1.1:9080 cookie server1 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

My situation was a little different as I was only looking to redirect a stats UI URL so I didn't have to go update each stats URL in our internal documentation. Here is what worked for my situation (in case it helps someone else):

```
userlist stats-auth
    group admin users adminuser
    group readonly users readonlyuser

    # Passwords created via mkpasswd -m sha-512 PASSWORD_HERE
    user adminuser password NOT_REAL_PASSWORD
    user readonlyuser password NOT_REAL_PASSWORD

listen stats

    # Used just for the initial connection before we redirect the user to https
    bind *:4711

    # Combined file containing server, intermediate and root CA certs along
    # with the private key for the server cert.
    bind *:4712 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/my-site-name_combined_cert_bundle_with_key.pem

    option dontlognull
    mode http
    option httplog

    # Redirect user from http port to https port
    http-request set-var(req.hostname) req.hdr(Host),field(1,:),lower
    http-request redirect code 301 location https://%[var(req.hostname)]:4712/ if !{ ssl_fc }

    acl AUTH            http_auth(stats-auth)
    acl AUTH_ADMIN      http_auth_group(stats-auth) admin

    stats enable

    # The only "site" for using these ports is the admin UI, so use '/' as
    # the base path instead of requiring something like '/haproxy_stats' or
    # '/stats' in order to display the UI.
    stats uri /

    # Force a login if not already authenticated
    stats http-request auth unless AUTH

    # Allow administrator functionality if user logged in using admin creds
    # (there are separate read-only username and password pairs)
    stats admin if AUTH_ADMIN
```

I left out the frontend and backend config as those are much longer/detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Source address through the `src` var.
Haproxy holds the requester IP under this , and can be used in acl's and other places.

For logging use it in the following manner : `%[src]`

Check out these links : [src](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#7.3.3-src) and [fetching-samples(under layer 4)](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/fetching_data_samples.html)

Comment: Basically I wanted to know the haproxy node's ip/host as the requester is issing. Ex: If the request is http ://1.1.1.1:8080, it needs to be forwarded to https ://1.1.1.1:8143 or http ://hello.com:8080 should be f/wed to https ://hello.com:8143